# gRPC json data in camel case

Tags: angular, grpc

I received a json data from gRPC and it is on Pascal case. I want it to be in camel case. I am using angular to access the gRPC service. Even when i serialize and convert the result into camel case, the output in angular is always in Pascal Case.
Below are the details.

protobuf message

```
message EmployeeRecord {
   string record = 1;
}
```

gRPC service

```
var serializedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});

var result = new Protos.EmployeeRecord() { record = serializedResult };

return result;
```

angular code

```
public getEmployees() : void{
    this.response = "";
    const service = new EmployeeServiceClient(this.gRPCUrl, null);
    const request = new EmployeeRecord();
    request.setMesssage('');

    service.fields(request, null, (err, response: EmployeeRecord) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          this.response = response.toObject().record;
        }
    });
  }
```

the result in this.response is always in Pascal Case

Answer (score 0):

You serialize to JSON on your server. Then you send the JSON in a `string` field of a protobuf message to angular.

It seems *very* unlikely that the string changes during the transmission.

It is much more likely that your server does not generate the data you expect (check with logging) or that you mixed something up in the client.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. But I already did that as you can see in my code above. I have 2 test application, one is a console app and the other an angular app. In the console app it is working fine, but in angular ounce i received the data it change into pascal case

Answer (score -1):

I am using the grpcui tool and have noticed a similar issue: the JSON Raw Request uses `myExampleFieldName` but the correct name is `my_example_field_name`

Maybe JSON does not allow underscores?